# Could not load file or assembly 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0' in app with Target Framework .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, adodb

I recompiled a dll library written for Net Framework 4.6.1 to be able to use it in my .Net Core 3.1 app, among the dependencies on the library there is ADODB, the path of the dll is `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll` and I did the same thing in my project, I don't get any compilation errors, I include the new library in my project, but during execution I get the error `Could not load file or assembly 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Cannot find the specified file.`
I have checked the properties of the adodb dll and notice
[image: ADODB assembly general]
[image: ADODB assembly version]

Same version also in this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies`
My question is my project being .Net Core is unable to use that dll?

If I include in my application project the library with which I recompiled the dll the error does not go out

Comment: That PIA is normally found in the GAC.  But .NETCore no longer uses the GAC, so the exception is expected.  Best thing to do is to select the COM reference and set the "Embed Interop Types" property to true.  If that's not desired for some reason (it better be a good reason) then you'll have to copy the dll into the build directory yourself.